# MINGW BOOST linking fails

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost, mingw

I'm trying to compile this code using MINGW and BOOST

http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~cotter/projects/SBP/

First I compiled this under Linux/UBUNTu and no problem. Then I tried under W764 using MINGW64. Up to level of creating object all was OK but linking failed. Here is a command

```
g++ issvm_evaluate.o svm_kernel_base.o svm_kernel_private_cache.o
svm_optimizer_base.o svm_optimizer_classification_biased_perceptron.o 
svm_optimizer_classification_biased_sbp.o
svm_optimizer_classification_biased_smo.o    
svm_optimizer_classification_biased_sparsifier.o   
svm_optimizer_classification_private_find_water_level.o  
svm_optimizer_classification_unbiased_perceptron.o    
svm_optimizer_classification_unbiased_sbp.o
svm_optimizer_classification_unbiased_smo.o 
svm_optimizer_classification_unbiased_sparsifier.o -o issvm_evaluate -fopenmp 
-LC:/boost_1_57_0/boost_1_57_0/bin.v2/libs/serialization/build/gcc-mingw-
4.9.0/release/ -lstdc++ -lm -LC:/boost_1_57_0/boost_1_570/bin.v2/libs/iostreams
/build\gcc-mingw-4.9.0/release/ -LC:/boost_1_57_0/boost_1_570/bin.v2  
/libs/program_options/build/gcc-mingw-4.9.0/release/
```

and response

```
issvm_evaluate.o:issvm_evaluate.cpp:(.text+0x2a81): undefined reference to boos
t::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::era
se(boost::archive::detail::basic_serializer const*)'
issvm_evaluate.o:issvm_evaluate.cpp:(.text+0x2ac1): undefined reference to `boos
t::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::era
se(boost::archive::detail::basic_serializer const*)'
```

Make file from LINUX using l option in gcc but I couldn't find build libraries or 
file ${patsubst %,-lboost_%,$(BOOST_LIBRARIES)} under LINUX so I suspect headers were just enough but under W7 i use L option and give directory to build libraries of boost. Any idea what the problem can be ??

As build directory of BOOST in W7 contains a lot of library files including dlls maybe l option of compiler should be used and linking to dll ??

I also tried with forward slashes but its the same

Comment: You don't actually *link* with any Boost libraries, you only tell the linker where to *find* libraries. The `-L` option adds a path to search, the `-l` (lower-case L) adds a library to link with (and it should be found in the paths provided by the `-L` options).

Comment: And you should probably install all Boost libraries to a common path, which makes it easier to add just a single `-L` option, if the path is not in the linkers default list (in which case you don't have to add a `-L` option at all).

Comment: Finally a little nit-picking note: The slash you use in the shown command-line *is* the forward slash. The backward slash is \.

Comment: Yes with slash i changed command to try but didnt change the text of the question

Comment: so should I add libraries with l option like in makefile for LINUX ?? which one as it is a lot of them. With .a .o and dll extension

Comment: Don't add the extension or prefixes. If you want to link with the `program_options` library, then you link with `program_options`, i.e. `-lprogram_options`. Generally speaking, with GCC if you want to link with the *file* `libY.ext` (no matter what `ext` is) then you add `-lY`.

Comment: so I set variable LIBRARY_PATH to dir where all libs are then added -llibboost_program_options-mgw49-1_57 -llibboost_iostreams-mgw49-1_57 -llibboost_regex-mgw49-_57 with the names of all libs but im getting 'can not find -llibboost.....the libfiles are in subdirectories under directory from LIBRARY_PATH. Any idea ??

Comment: If a library `libX` is in the linkers search path, you only add `X` to the linker command line like `-lX`. In your case it should be e.g. `-lboost_program_options`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that i fixed my problem. The problem was multiple using of -L option with different paths which don't give multiple search paths, only 1st -L is working. Additionally
library must be explicitly specified by -l option, setting just -L which points to correct directory with sub directories with libraries was not enough. Global setting of library path by LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is working so I replaced -L with this and copied all requested libraries to just one directory and specified by -l requested libraries.